# Security of a Docker image

Tags: docker

I am considering to package a Rust application into a Docker container.

The current version of that application contains various credential files used to register to Discord API or Google API through a service account key.

Would these files be accessibles if I package my application as such?

**[EDIT: added Dockerfile]**

```
FROM rust:1.28.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/<application>
COPY . .

RUN cargo install --force --path .

CMD ["<application>"]
```

Comment: do you have credentials in files that get copied into the docker image? and could you provide the dockerfile?

Comment: I guess I would need to since these credential files need to be loaded by my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never put actual credentials into anything that might not be accessed by you and only you.
You basically have two options:

1) Have your application pull the required credentials from its environment, then set these variables when you start the container. see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/deploy-app/6_define_environment_variables/)

2) Have your application read the credentials from a config file, that doesn't get pulled into the docker image. Then, when running the container, mount that file into it, see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

You could actually do both: Have an environment variable that tells your application whether it should look for a config file ( maybe in production) and if that variable is unset, check the environment (for development).

**Edit:** It's best practice to create a `.dockerignore` File in your build-context, containing the name (or path) of the file holding the credentials.

Comment: Just to be sure, I should then add the credentials files to the .dockerignore file to make sure they are not pulled into the docker image right?

Comment: yeah. thanks, forgot to mention that. updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added the Dockerfile too in my initial question as per your request